# How to set notification to clear itself on click?

Tags: android, android-notifications

How to set my notification to clear itself on click?

I've set `autoCancel(true)` but it doesn't work

My code:

```
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Update for you")
                .setContentText("Please click here to see the update information")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), 
                                                           R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pList)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_read, "Read", pRead)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_list, "All Updates", pList)
                .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                      (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL)

```
n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to test it but I don't know why sometimes my notification is showed but sometimes it doesn't :(

Answer (score 3):

`setAutoCancel()` of `Notification.Builder` is introduced in API 11. Perhaps, your minimum version is lower than API 11.

`setAutoCancel()` is also available in `NotificationCompat.Builder` class which is added in Support library

```
Notification n  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Update for you")
                .setContentText("Please click here to see the update information")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), 
                                                           R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pList)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_read, "Read", pRead)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_list, "All Updates", pList)
                .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my `android:minSdkVersion` is 13

Comment: btw, what's the different between Notification and NotificationCompat? Should I use NotificationCompat insted of Notification?

Comment: No, we still using `Notification` to display notification. `NotificationCompat` is helper class for accessing features in `Notification` introduced after API level 4 in a backwards compatible fashion.

Answer (score 1):

**SetAutoCancel(true)**

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Quiz Tap")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            /*.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))*//*Notification with Image*/
            **.setAutoCancel(true)**
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```