# Android notification clear just after clicked

Tags: android, notifications

i want to create a notification that user can't close it by drag to left or right.
user must click o that to close notification

my code is :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                     .setContentTitle("title")
                     .setContentText("text")
                     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tt)
                     .setLargeIcon( BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_tt))
                     .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                     .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                     .setOngoing(true).build();
                     n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

but it dosnot work
any idea ?

Comment: Doesn't the notification display at all or is it just displayed as a normal notification?

Comment: @the_Seppi notification displays but it can't close anway

Comment: Does it display as ongoing or normal?

Comment: Have used  `notificationManager.cancel(0);`?

Comment: @the_Seppi  it displays as ongoing , it displays but you can't close it by click on it !!
( i dont want AutoCancel )

Comment: And how do you listen for the click?

Comment: @PiyushGupta where i must use it?

Comment: @the_Seppi if click on it , it opens intent "http://google.com", first line's of code

Comment: Where you want to close notification. Like on click of button or click on notification. You need to pass there notification id

Comment: @PiyushGupta in lines 1-2 of code  i used intent and pIntent , in line 8 i used .setContentIntent(pIntent)  , where i must use .cancel(0); ?

Comment: After your notify function

Comment: @PiyushGupta i used this :
      notificationManager.notify(0, n);
      notificationManager.cancel(0);
and it Doesn't the notification display at all

Comment: Check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479428/android-notification-intent-to-clear-it-self , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558619/how-to-set-notification-to-clear-itself-on-click

Comment: just use setAutoCancel(true);

Comment: @Harry i dont want setAutoCancel(true); :)) if i used setAutoCancel  the notification can close when user drags it to left ot right . i want notification close just if user click it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use both functions to retain the notification,

```
nBuilder.setOngoing(true);
nBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

It can be cancelled only when user taps on it.
Find setAutoCancel in this [Managing Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Managing).
Hope this helped!